# T-SQL how to get four digit year value using two digit year part

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a string value 16******* that I call substring on to get the first two digits of the string literal

```
SUBSTRING(@CourtCaseNumber,1,2)
```

I then need  a function that will take the string argument(16) and return to me the four digit year value, 2016. Some will be of 99, therefore I'll  need a year value of 1999, 98 will need to be 1998, 15 will need to be 2015 etc.

So it should look something like this. I can't find a function that will do this for me.

```
NEEDEDFUNCTION(SUBSTRING(@CourCaseNumber,1,2)
```

Comment: Step 1 - determine when to prepend 19 and when to prepend 20.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So based on @Gordon Linoff answer function will look as below:

```
create function dbo.your_name
(
    @yearYY nvarchar(2)
)
RETURNS nvarchar(4)
as
begin
    declare @yearYYYY nvarchar(4)
    set @yearYYYY = (SELECT ((CASE WHEN @yearYY >= 50 THEN '19' 
                        ELSE '20' END) + @yearYY
                    ) as yyyy)
    return @yearYYYY
end
```

test:

```
select dbo.your_name ('70')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just use `case`:

```
SELECT ((CASE WHEN LEFT(@CourtCaseNumber, 2) >= '50' THEN '19' ELSE '20' END) +
        LEFT(@CourtCaseNumber, 2)
       ) as yyyy
```

I'm making up the "'50'" as a reasonable boundary for distinguishing between the centuries.

EDIT:

Don't use a function for this.  Just create a computed column:

```
alter table t
    add yyyy as ((CASE WHEN LEFT(@CourtCaseNumber, 2) >= '50' THEN '19' ELSE '20' END) +
                 LEFT(@CourtCaseNumber, 2)
                ) ;
```

That way, the value is available to anyone who uses the table.